# Xamarin Post Json data Error (405 Method Not Allowed)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Guys i have to make program with posting. Using Postman for it. I need get data from a link. That link doesnt allow Get method. Its my link : http://api.lokmanecza.com/api/GetControlPackageList/1/1
I took my datas with using postman. And convert that jsons to c#. I trying post it but its giving error.

Its my error:

"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).'"

Its my codes :

```
string url = $"http://api.lokmanecza.com/api/GetControlPackageList/1/1";
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                LoginApiResponseModel rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginApiResponseModel>(response);
                var content = new StringContent(rootObj.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result =   client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
                lbl.Text = rootObj.InvoiceID.ToString();
                
            }
```

Comment: `client.GetStringAsync` is a GET, not a POST.  It is telling you that GET is not allowed.  Why are you doing a GET and then a POST to the exact same url?

Comment: @Jason I tried without client.GetStringAsync too then its giving another error like : `"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0.'"` But in that datas have for example "InvoiceID. " I need take that data from that link. So how can i do it ?

Comment: do you have any documentation for this API?  What data are you supposed to send to `GetControlPackageList`?

Comment: @Jason No brother. My Manager just gave me that link and http://api.lokmanecza.com/api/GetControlPackageDetail/4640350 that link. He wants i take infos from that jsons. For example like ı need to take "OrderSalesID" inside of that first link i shared in my post.  I need take that info and write it to a label. Like that. I kinda stuck. Coz web isnt doesnt support get when i enter link to internet. But i need get datas inside of it. I kinda stuck in that i think i dont know how to do

Comment: nobody here can tell you how some random webservice works without any documentation.

Comment: @Jason thank you brother. I will talk with my manager again for documentations. Sorry im just a stuedent and internship devoloper sorry for being newbie. thanks for help <3

Comment: simply calling that url with a POST returns json data

Comment: `var data = await client.PostAsync(url,null);` should returns json, then you will need to deserialize it into a C# model to extract the data

Comment: @Jason thank you very much <3 It will help me a lot!